# How to select geometry and remove it with slope mask?

Tags: shaders, geometry, masking, select

[image]

Program: Blender 2.9.2-4.0

Geometry and mask created in Gaea

I'm facing a problem, I don't understand how I can select vertices for further deletion, ONLY those in the white area?

My goal, by any means necessary, is to remove the white areas to leave only the slope of the rock.

I would appreciate anyone who can tell me how to resolve this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Deletion of geometry based on slope (*Geometry Nodes*)

Let's say you have the following geometry. By computing the *Dot Product* between your object normals and a z-axis vector, you would get

- 1: where face is pointing up
- 0: where face is pointing sideways (x or y)
- -1: where face is pointing down

In our case, we want to delete what is near 1.

[image: Initial setup with some annotations]

The geometry nodes are quite simple. Just compute de *Dot Product* and feed it to a *Delete Geometry* node :

[image: Geometry nodes that delete geometry based on slope]

You can adjust the threshold by tweaking the *Greather Than* node.